# SSL not working in HTTPS-Server Lib based on Express

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https

I have made my own HTTPS-Server Lib based on Express, everything works fine except that I cannot GET the given Website via SSL. I have made self-signed certificates like this and added "localhost" or "localhost:3000" (I also tried 443 standard port) as Common Name:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out certificate.pem -days 365 -nodes
```

This is my Class:

```
export class HttpsServer {

    private _serverInstance: express.Application = express();

    constructor(port: number, options: Options) {
        this.init(port, options);
    }

    init(port: number, options: Options) {
        https.createServer(options.https, this._serverInstance);
        this._serverInstance.use(cors(options.cors));
        if (!!options.directory) {
            this._serverInstance.use(express.static(options.directory));
        }
        this.listen(port);
    }

    get(route: string, handler: RequestHandler) {
        this._serverInstance.get(route, handler);
    }

    listen(port: number) {
        this._serverInstance.listen(port);
    }
}
```

This is my Instance:

```
const options: Options = {
  cors: {
    origin: ['*']
  },
  https: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/key.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/certificate.pem', 'utf8'),
  },
  directory: './httpdocs'
};

const currentHandler: RequestHandler = function handler (req, res) {
  console.log(req.route)
  // res.send('... registered ' + req.route.stack[0].method + '-request on route ' + req.route.path)
};

function bootstrap() {
  const server = new HttpsServer(3000, options);

  server.get('/', currentHandler);
}

bootstrap();
```

Insomnia says:

```
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

Firefox says:

```
SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

Over HTTP the site is visible. What am I doing wrong? Thx

Edit with solution:

```
init(httpPort: number, httpsPort: number, options: Options) {
        const httpServer = http.createServer(this._serverInstance);
        const httpsServer = https.createServer(options.https, this._serverInstance);

        this._serverInstance.use(cors(options.cors));
        if (!!options.directory) {
            this._serverInstance.use(express.static(options.directory));
        }

        httpServer.listen(httpPort);
        httpsServer.listen(httpsPort);
    }
```

I need a const named httpsServer with a listen method. Http/Https also need different ports...

Comment: SUGGESTION: start from scratch, with a new test project.  Follow these instructions (exactly): https://timonweb.com/javascript/running-expressjs-server-over-https/.  See if it works.  Please post back what you find.